# vue.js vuetify : test-utils w Jest how to match text when using icon

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

given the following generated html

```
<a href="#" class="primaryInversed v-btn v-btn--large v-btn--round"
   <div class="v-btn__content">STOP!
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon v-icon--right material-icons">pause_circle_outline</i>
   </div>
</a>
```

when I test with the .toEqual Jest matcher

```
console.log(playLink.text())
expect(playLink.text()).toEqual("STOP!");
```

test is failing because of the icon

```
  console.log tests/unit/Heading.spec.js:46
    STOP!
          pause_circle_outline
```

It foes not fail if I use the .toMatch watcher

```
expect(playLink.text()).toMatch(/STOP!/);
```

Is it the normal test to be written or is there anyway to use the .toEqual watcher ?

NOTE : I used 'mount' and not 'shallowMount' as I need to generate html from vuetify components

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to wrap the `<v-btn>`'s text content in a `<span>`, and use [`wrapper.find(selector)`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/find.html) to select the `<span>` to get its text:

*foo.vue template:*

```
<v-btn>
  <span class="text">STOP!</span>
  <v-icon>pause_circle_outline</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

*foo.spec.js*

```
it('contains the expected text', () => {
  expect(wrapper.find('.text').text()).toEqual('STOP!');
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yv2j76j199?module=src/Foo.spec.js)